# Fuse Identification

Tags: identification, fuses

Would anyone be able to help me identify this fuse? The markings on it are: "51NM 250V 1.6A". It is a glass 5x20MM fuse, I am just wondering if it is a fast or slow blow fuse so I can order a replacement.

[image]

Comment: The letters 'MDA' would be a slow-blow fuse, often a coil of wire with a spring load, effectively an overrated fuse. Note that MDA is not the only slow blow fuse type.

Comment: Is it definitely the original fuse or might someone else have replaced it with something "close"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a fast acting fuse: [see here](http://www.dainfuse.com/51nm.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting the spec sheet!

Answer (score 2):

If you can still see the fuse wire inside the glass, and it is a simple wire, it probably was a fast-blow fuse.

I think the great majority of fuses are fast-blow, so itis probably safe to assume that it is (or was :-) ) a fast blow.  Using a fast blow in place of a slow blow should be safe, but it may blow with no fault, where a slow-blow wouldn't.

Comment: Indeed, though if a fast-blow blows, you have to then figure out if there is a fault, or if a slow blow would have been appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at the end cap where the fuse rating is stamped.  If it includes the letter "F", it's quick blow. "T" is slow blow.

For example, "F1.6A 250V" would be a quick blow.

Answer (score 0):

[51NM](http://www.ibselectronics.com/ibsstore/datasheet/52NM.pdf) is a series name from Hollyland. They are fast blow fuses. Something like [0034.1518](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/schurter-inc/0034.1518/486-1235-ND/639672) from Schurter would work.